# Recommender System with Time as the dependent variable and not ratings

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I'm currently designing a recommender system in watching videos (all with same duration). I have the user_id and the video_id and I have the data for users's watch duration for the video_id.

I initially used surprise package and SVD algorithm but I get an RMSE of (3000s) which is greater than the mean of the watch duration of the dataset (2500s). I wonder If I'm doing this approach incorrectly?

I think the model isn't overfitting to the data because I get the same RMSE from the CV result and the hold out set.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you tried different values of CV? If the CV is too high compared to the data, maybe it is overvitting.

Comment: @Nicolas M, I'm the one who posted the question, No the model isn't overfitting because i get the same RMSE when I try to cross validate the model and trying the fitted SVD model to my hold out set. The RMSE im getting is still very high compared to the mean of the duration in the dataset... Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Ok but first, if all videos have the same duration, why do you want the model to learn it? The models are built to learn on data with variability.

Comment: The same duration are for the total runtime of the videos not the watch duration of each user...

Comment: Could you share some code and result? I don't know what a (3000s) RMSE is...